# Is $\psi_\lambda =1_E+\lambda\psi+\lambda^2 /2 \phi^2$ a Linear Map

Tags: linear-algebra

E is a Vector Space of dimension n over R and $\phi$   is an endomorphism of E
such that $ \phi\circ\phi\circ\phi$=0_E
For each $\lambda$ in R, $\psi_\lambda =1_E+\lambda\psi+\lambda^2 /2 \phi^2$

1. I have to prove that $\psi_\lambda$ is a Linear map for all $\lambda$ in R.
2. I have to prove that $\psi_\lambda$  with the composition of Linear Applications is a group.

-> it is clear to me that $\psi$ is a Linear Map, since it is  the addition of automorphisms

-> But I need to prove that it is a group, for that, I need to prove associativity, existence of identity and that every element has an inverse.

-> I know I have to prove $(\psi_\lambda1\circ\psi_\lambda2)\circ\psi\lambda3= \psi_\lambda1\circ(\psi_\lambda2\circ\psi\lambda3)$

-> for the id I need a $\psi_\lambda1$ such that $\psi_\lambda1\circ\psi_\lambda =\psi_\lambda$

-> for the inverse, I can think of $\phi^3=0 =>\phi^2=\phi^-1(0)$ but I am not able to go any further

Comment: So if this was a linear transformation, what should it look like if we evaluated $\psi (ax)$ for $a$ a scalar and $x$ a vector in $E$?

Comment: $\alpha\psi(x)$

Comment: You can't assume that $\phi = 0$, since you can take $\phi : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ defined by $\phi(x) := Ax$ for
$$
 A = \begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: It's linear simply because it's a linear combination of endomorphisms. Do you mean to ask, is $\psi$ invertible for all $\alpha$? (This is true, and, unlike the question as posed, this really does use that $\phi^3 = 0_E$.)

Comment: Tks Travis, that makes sense. No, I am simply asked to prove that $\psi\ $  is a Linear Transformation and next I am asked to prove that $\psi$ under composition is a Group. I cant see how am I going to prove associativity, id and existence of inverse.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: How does the fact that $\psi$ is defined using the constant $1$ effect our ability to factor out the scalar $a$ when evaluating $\psi(ax)$?

Also, you cannot assume that $\phi$ is a zero map.

Comment: Sir Jective , I had to edit the question, sorry

Comment: Would you mind copy pasting the formula for $\psi$ into the question? My phone won't read the tex in the title and I'd like to make sure I understand it correctly.

Comment: of course not, tks a lot   \psi=1+\alpha\phi+\alpha^2 /2 \phi^2

Comment: $\psi=1+\alpha\phi+\alpha^2 /2 \phi^2$

Comment: I notoced you have yet to accept any answers for your questions. Note that you can do this by clicking underneath the down arrow on the check mark for the answer you would like to accept.

Comment: tks for the tip Sir Jective

Comment: Anytime Ziloric.